# Android Studio, Flutter нет кнопки "подписать и выпустить APK / Bundle"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, build, keystore

Всем доброго времени суток, суть в чем...
Раньше чтобы упростить себе жизнь всегда пользовался в AS кнопкой Build, дабы подписать и выпустить релиз приложения.
Сейчас приобрел новый ПК, перетащил исходники и после запуска проекта в AS и даже после создания новых проектов в AS, пропали пункты в меню [image: Скриншот с AS]

Может я что то не учел, когда настраивал Flutter и AS?

Какие скрины мне отправить?

Совсем нету желания создавать ключи с помощью -keytool

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте Android Studio -> Open an existing Android Studio Project -> укажите путь к паке ***android*** внутри вашего проекта -> будут нужные пункты в меню :)

Вы открыли флатер проект в студии, поэтому интерфейс у вас флатеровский, а нужен нативный.